# Minimum volume enclosing ellipsoid in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, optimization, minimization

I have a following [dataset](http://textuploader.com/d1i3x). The goal is minimize the volume of ellipsoid that encloses those points using CVX. I did this using the following code:

```
cvx_begin
    variable A(n,n) symmetric
    variable b(n)
    maximize( det_rootn( A ) )
    subject to
        norms( A * x + b * ones( 1, m ), 2 ) <= 1;


cvx_end


clf
noangles = 200;
angles   = linspace( 0, 2 * pi, noangles );
ellipse  = A \ [ cos(angles) - b(1) ; sin(angles) - b(2) ];
plot( x(1,:), x(2,:), 'ro', ellipse(1,:), ellipse(2,:), 'b-' );
axis off
```

But how can I minimize a volume of ellipsoid enclosing a five points out of given 20? Not just random 5 points, but the ones that would result in an ellipsis as small as possible?

My idea was to calculate the distance between the center of ellipsoid to the farthest point and then remove it from dataset. Then reconstruct a new ellipsis and repeat. Step by step narrow it down to the last five points.

Can someone help with the code, or just give a hint how it can be done in a more smooth way?

Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to find principal eigen direction?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42293613/how-to-find-principal-eigen-direction)

Comment: Your problem is exactly the one the question linked has, but the OP of the qeustion already has code working in 3D. PCA is the answer.

Comment: Oh, ok. Thanks, I will investigate it. Sorry for duplicating.

Comment: No worries, just triying to help out.